# Fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am in the process of porting an older rails app that is running on Heroku to a new Heroku instance. It appears to be built correctly. When I try to run `rails console` in bash, I get:

```
In file included from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.5/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:36:0,
                 from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.5/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from /app/.ruby_inline/ruby-2.4.0/Inline_Dalli__Ring_ca4ff83feb7b263c9bd4987d8e541e30.c:1:
/app/vendor/ruby-2.4.5/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/defines.h:101:10: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdio.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I get this when I try to run many commands including bundle and rake

I am using ruby 2.4.5 and rails 5.1.1 on the 
heroku-18 stack

Is there any buildpack that I can use to fix this?

I have tried getting a buildpack witg libc6-dev, but that appears to be a dead-end...

Any advice would be much appreciated...